# How do I use TreeMap java?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, treemap

I have been writing this line:

```
Map s_AvailableGameTables = Collection.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap());
```

And got the following error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method synchronizedMap(java.util.TreeMap)
  location: interface java.util.Collection

Although I wrote

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
```

What is the reason for that?
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a simple typo. It should be [`Collections`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), not [`Collection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).

---

Try,

```
Map s_AvailableGameTables = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap());
```

Comment: Detecting a typo causes 15 upvotes. Nice! You've got my +1 as wel :D

Answer (score 3):

A synchronized TreeMap is rather slow. It's probably better to use [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) if you want a navigatable map that supports concurrency.